# When class features update at Xth level, is it my class or character level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, class-feature

I'm new to Pathfinder and interested in multiclassing, and I'm unsure how some abilities which get upgraded by level work.

For example, if I were to take 2 levels in [Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist), I'd get *[Poison Resistance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Poison-Resistance-Ex-):*

> Poison Resistance (Ex): At 2nd level, an alchemist gains a +2 bonus on all saving throws against poison. This bonus increases to +4 at 5th level, and then again to +6 at 8th level. At 10th level, an alchemist becomes completely immune to poison.

Suppose I then stop putting levels into Alchemist, and start putting levels into something else like Wizard. When I reach level 10, will I still unlock poison immunity, even if I didn't put more than 2 levels into Alchemist?

There are other abilities like this, and while some say class level others are general like this and leave me unsure.

Comment: Hi Rasaru, I rewrote parts of your question to attempt to make what you were asking clearer. Please check I preserved the intent of your question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class level.

**Pathfinder Core Rules, Page 31**

> Note that there are a number of effects and prerequisites that rely on the character's level or Hit Dice. Such effects are always based on the total number of levels or Hit Dice a character possesses, not just those from one class. **The exception to this is class abilities, most of which are based on the total number of class levels that a character possesses of that particular class.**

Logically, a great way to think about this is "would it make sense the other way around". Sure, if you start an alchemist, you might imagine your character growing stronger with each level, regardless of whether or not it is in alchemy. But if it relied on character level, any level 9 character could immediately gain immunity to poison by picking up a level of Alchemist.

Comment: Makes sense thanks for clearing that up for me I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

That is class level, so at 5th level of Alchemist the bonus would increase to a +4. General rule of thumb is it is always class level unless it specifically says level (Even in that scenario I can't think of a single thing off the top of my head that uses actual level).

Comment: Exception to the general rule: if "level" is used in the context of a class, it means "class level" as well. E.g. "*Countersong (Su)*: At 1st level, a bard learns to [...]"

Comment: Thanks MrLemon that's a big part of what I was wondering.